# Java multi dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to search a multi-dimensional array and print the numbers greater than 7 with their locations.

This code compiles and runs without any errors, but doesn't provide any output.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
class Sarr{

   public static void main(String args[]){    
     int[][] numArray = {{1,2,5,6,4,0},{6,0,1,2},{1,7,3,4},{3,5,6,8,5}};      
     arr(numArray);
   }

   private static void arr(int [][] array){

   int val = 7;

   for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++) {

          if (array[r][c] > val){

             System.out.println("Value found was " + val + "["+r+"]"+"["+c+"]");

           }
        }            
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what does it output now that you added an 8?

Comment: you edit the test array, which you pass as a reference, on my machine it o/p as `Value found was 7[3][3]`

Comment: tnx all... i totally forgot to add a  value greater than 7, to my array. i edit it and compiled it. now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no number greater than 7 in your array. If you want it to print 7's you will need to change your if statement to

```
if(array[r][c]>=val) {
    //Print
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your test array does not have any element which is > 7 ...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're looking for strictly `array[r][c] > 7` none of the values in your array are greater than 7.